# Show at the end of a document an answer key based on a specific environment

Tags: lists, questionnaire

I'm making a list of math exercises for my students. Here's an example of the environment I use to create it:

```
 \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[brazil]{babel}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \newcounter{questionnumber}
 \newcommand{\makequestion}[2]{\refstepcounter{questionnumber}\par\vspace{1em}\noindent\textbf{(#1\hspace{0mm}-\hspace{0mm}\textbf{#2})\hspace{1mm}Question\hspace{0.3em}\thequestionnumber.}\\\vspace{-4mm}\ignorespaces}
 \newcounter{lettercounter}[questionnumber]
 \newcommand{\alternative}{(\alph{lettercounter})}
 \newenvironment{options}{\begin{list}{\alternative}{\usecounter{lettercounter}}}{\end{list}}



 \begin{document}

 \makequestion{MIT}{2014}

 What do you think about life?
 \begin{options}
 \item I think it's a word.
 \item I think it's not a word. 
 \end{options}

 \makequestion{MIT}{2011}

 Is it a boy or a girl?
 \begin{options}
 \item A boy
 \item Yes. 
 \end{options}

 \end{document}
```

I want to make an answer key at the end of the document, with this structure:

Question 1 - A

Question 2 - B

but I have no idea how to do that. Could you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of defining everything yourself you could use a dedicated package like [`exsheets`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets). Then you can easily print solutions at the end of the document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{exsheets}

% cloning the exercise headings from the question:
\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{myheading}{default}{
  join = {
    title[l,B]subtitle[r,B](0pt,0pt) ;
    title[r,B]number[l,B](.333em,0pt)
  } ,
  attach = {
    main[l,vc]title[l,vc](0pt,0pt) ;
    main[r,vc]points[l,vc](\marginparsep,0pt)
  }
}
\SetupExSheets{
  headings = myheading ,
  subtitle-format = \bfseries\mysubtitleformat ,
  question/name = Question ,
  solution/name = Question
}
\newcommand*\mysubtitleformat[1]{(#1)\space}

% define a list options which enumerates (a), (b), ...    
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{options}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[options]{label=(\alph*)}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}[subtitle=MIT-2014]
  What do you think about life?
  \begin{options}
    \item I think it's a word.\label{MIT-2014-solution}
    \item I think it's not a word.
  \end{options}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  \ref{MIT-2014-solution}
\end{solution}

\begin{question}[subtitle=MIT-2011]
  Is it a boy or a girl?
  \begin{options}
    \item A boy
    \item Yes.\label{MIT-2011-solution}
  \end{options}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  \ref{MIT-2011-solution}
\end{solution}

\section*{Solutions}
\SetupExSheets{headings = runin}
\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Problem is, I already have a file with more than 1000 exercises formatted using the same environment I've shown you. I want to do exactly what you did, but isn't there a way of doing it in a way that I could merge the definitions I've made? Oh, and thanks for helping, by the way.